# How to solve the problem with aggregate function nested in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as qty,STRING_AGG(
                  distinct
                    case order_account
                    when 0 then
                    CONCAT(CONCAT('ABC (',CAST(sum(CASE WHEN order_account = 0 THEN 1 END) AS VARCHAR(5))),')')
                    when 1 then
                    CONCAT(CONCAT('DEF (',CAST(sum(CASE WHEN order_account = 1 THEN 1 END) AS VARCHAR(5))),')')
                    when 2 then
                    CONCAT(CONCAT('LDW (',CAST(sum(CASE WHEN order_account = 2 THEN 1 END) AS VARCHAR(5))),')')
                    when 3 then
                    CONCAT(CONCAT('APQ (',CAST(sum(CASE WHEN order_account = 3 THEN 1 END) AS VARCHAR(5))),')')
                    end,
                  ', ') as order_accounts
```

Basically i am trying to get a sum of all the accounts into one column with there respected individual quantity.

its giving a error below:

ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested
LINE 6:                      CONCAT(CONCAT('SMR (',CAST(sum(CASE WHE.

Expected output should be based on the qty

```
qty order_accounts
23  ABC(20), DEF(3) 
45  ABC(30), LDW(15)
```

with the following query it's working like it

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as qty,
                       STRING_AGG(
                        distinct
                           case order_account
                              when 0 then 'ABC'
                              when 1 then 'DEF'
                            when 2 then 'LDW'
                             when 3 then 'APQ'
                         end,


                         ',') as order_accounts


qty order_accounts
20  ABC,DEF
45  LDW,APQ
```

I have to add a individual account quantity with the accounts

Comment: well...the error message says it all

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no need to nest the CONCAT() calls, Those expressions can be simplified to `CONCAT('ABC (', sum(CASE WHEN order_account = 0 THEN 1 END)::text,')')`

Comment: This error is usually solved by introducing a second level of queries (e.g. a sub-query or common table expression). But you haven't provided enough information so that this could be answered. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you can check the sample data now

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the `string_agg()` is for.

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select concat('ABC (', count(*) filter (where order_account = 0), ') ',
              'DEF (', count(*) filter (where order_account = 1), ') ',
              'LDW (', count(*) filter (where order_account = 2), ') ',
              'APQ (', count(*) filter (where order_account = 3), ')'
             ) as order_accounts
```

Comment: in the above condition it will print all the values even i dont have present any record something like it ABC(12) DEF(0) LDW(0) APQ(0)

Comment: i want to print only those which is required for it

Comment: Also as you can see i was aggregate all the category into one in my query with the final qty but as per the case of your aggregate failed to work.

Comment: string_agg group all the records in one row with , seperate